# Remove unused blank space in tables-XSLT/XSL-FO

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have table created in PDF using Apache FOP.

But the text in the table cells (Table Headers and contents) has blank/white spaces surrounding the text and thus consuming lots of space.

The PDF has limitation of 120 characters and thus unable to display all the text.

Please suggest how to define widths of the table columns to hold only the text and without any blank/unused

The table is created dynamically

Comment: Thanks.But the answer for the other question( Remove whitespace/blank spaces in table columns XSL-FO) is not visible.Hence reposted the question without including the link for PDF table attachment. please suggest the best way to handle this issue

Comment: Huh? There is no answer on the other attachment. Do you mean that the image you tried to link to isn't visible on the other question? I suggest editing the other question instead of asking a new one. I will fix the link for you in the other question.